# Bootstrap MOdel Have Issue?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

> IN this Model Forget Password not work properly. anyone check this
>   issue. when click on forget password then show forget password form
>   and  login button. KIndly check issue and resolve someone..............................................................................................................

```js
/*
 *
 * login-register modal
 * Autor: Creative Tim
 * Web-autor: creative.tim
 * Web script: http://creative-tim.com
 *
 */
function showRegisterForm(){
    $('.loginBox').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('.registerBox').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.login-footer').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $('.register-footer').fadeIn('fast');

        });
        $('.modal-title').html('Register with');
    });
    $('.error').removeClass('alert alert-danger').html('');

}

function showPasswordForm(){
   $('#loginModal .loginBox').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('.passwordBox').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.login-footer').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $('.register-footer').fadeIn('fast');

        });
        $('.modal-title').html('Forget Password');
    });
    $('.error').removeClass('alert alert-danger').html('');
}
function showLoginForm(){
    $('#loginModal .registerBox').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('.loginBox').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.register-footer').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $('.login-footer').fadeIn('fast');
        });
        
       

        $('.modal-title').html('Login with');
    });
     $('.error').removeClass('alert alert-danger').html('');
}



function openLoginModal(){
    showLoginForm();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');
    }, 230);

}
function openRegisterModal(){
    showRegisterForm();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');
    }, 230);

}
function openPasswordModal(){
    showPasswordForm();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');
    }, 230);

}
function loginAjax(){
    /*   Remove this comments when moving to server
    $.post( "/login", function( data ) {
            if(data == 1){
                window.location.replace("/home");
            } else {
                 shakeModal();
            }
        });
    */

/*   Simulate error message from the server   */
     shakeModal();
}

function shakeModal(){
    $('#loginModal .modal-dialog').addClass('shake');
             $('.error').addClass('alert alert-danger').html("Invalid email/password combination");
             $('input[type="password"]').val('');
             setTimeout( function(){
                $('#loginModal .modal-dialog').removeClass('shake');
    }, 1000 );
}
```

```css
/*
 *
 * login-register modal
 * Autor: Creative Tim
 * Web-autor: creative.tim
 * Web script: http://creative-tim.com
 * 
 */
 
/*  Shake animation  */

@charset "UTF-8";

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
      -o-animation-duration: 1s;
         animation-duration: 1s;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
      -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
         animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.animated.hinges {
 -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
      -o-animation-duration: 2s;
         animation-duration: 2s;
}

.animated.slow {
 -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
      -o-animation-duration: 3s;
         animation-duration: 3s;
}

.animated.snail {
 -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 4s;
      -o-animation-duration: 4s;
         animation-duration: 4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake {
 0%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0);}
 10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);}
 20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-webkit-transform: translateX(10px);}
}

@-moz-keyframes shake {
 0%, 100% {-moz-transform: translateX(0);}
 10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-moz-transform: translateX(-10px);}
 20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-moz-transform: translateX(10px);}
}

@-o-keyframes shake {
 0%, 100% {-o-transform: translateX(0);}
 10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-o-transform: translateX(-10px);}
 20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-o-transform: translateX(10px);}
}

@keyframes shake {
 0%, 100% {transform: translateX(0);}
 10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {transform: translateX(-10px);}
 20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {transform: translateX(10px);}
}

.shake {
 -webkit-animation-name: shake;
 -moz-animation-name: shake;
 -o-animation-name: shake;
 animation-name: shake;
}

.login .modal-dialog{
    width: 350px;
}
.login .modal-footer{
    border-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px;
}
.login .modal-header {
    border: 0 none;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px;
/*     padding: 11px 15px; */
}
.login .modal-body{
/*     background-color: #eeeeee; */
}
.login .division {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto 18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.login .division .line {
    border-top: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 34%;
}
.login .division .line.l {
    left: 0;
}
.login .division .line.r {
    right: 0;
}
.login .division span {
    color: #424242;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.login .box .social {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.login .social .circle{
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 17px;
    padding: 15px;
}
.login .social .circle .fa{
    font-size: 16px;
}
.login .social .facebook{
    background-color: #455CA8;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.login .social .google{
    background-color: #F74933;
}
.login .social .github{
    background-color: #403A3A;
}
.login .facebook:hover{
    background-color: #6E83CD;
}
.login .google:hover{
    background-color: #FF7566;
}
.login .github:hover{
    background-color: #4D4D4d;;
}
.login .forgot {
    color: #797979;
    margin-left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.login .btn-login, .registerBox .passwordBox .btn-register{
    background-color: #00BBFF;
    border-color: #00BBFF;
    border-width: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}
.login .btn-login:hover, .registerBox .passwordBox .btn-register:hover{
    background-color: #00A4E4;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.login .form-control{
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) inset;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.login .form-control:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.16);
}
.login .form-control:focus{
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) inset;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.login .box .form input[type="text"], .login .box .form input[type="password"] {
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 46px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 13px 12px;
    width: 100%;
}


@media (max-width:400px){
    .login .modal-dialog{
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.big-login, .big-register{
    background-color: #00bbff;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border-width: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 16px 60px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.big-login:hover{
    background-color: #00A4E4;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.big-register{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0);
    color: #00bbff;
    border-color: #00bbff;
}
.big-register:hover{
    border-color: #00A4E4;
    color:  #00A4E4;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login/Register Modal by Creative Tim</title>

 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />


 <style>body{padding-top: 60px;}</style>

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                 <a class="btn big-login" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLoginModal();">Log in</a>
                 <a class="btn big-register" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openRegisterModal();">Register</a></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        </div>


   <div class="modal fade login" id="loginModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog login animated">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Login with</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="box">
                             <div class="content">
                                <div class="social">
                                    <a class="circle github" href="#">
                                        <i class="fa fa-github fa-fw"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a id="google_login" class="circle google" href="#">
                                        <i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a id="facebook_login" class="circle facebook" href="#">
                                        <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="division">
                                    <div class="line l"></div>
                                      <span>or</span>
                                    <div class="line r"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="error"></div>
                                <div class="form loginBox">
                                    <form method="" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                                    <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                                    <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                                    <input class="btn btn-default btn-login" type="button" value="Login" onclick="loginAjax()">
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="content registerBox" style="display:none;">
                             <div class="form">
                                <form method="" html="{:multipart=>true}" data-remote="true" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                                <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                                <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                                <input id="password_confirmation" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="password_confirmation">
                                <input class="btn btn-default btn-register" type="button" value="Create account" name="commit">
                                </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      <div class="box">
                            <div class="contents passwordBox" style="display:none;">
                             <div class="form">
                                <form method=""  accept-charset="UTF-8">
                                <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="Phonne">
                                <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                                <input class="btn btn-default btn-register" type="button" value="Update" name="commit">
                                </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="forgot login-footer">
                            <span>Looking to
                                 <a href="javascript: showRegisterForm();">create an account</a>
                            ?</span>
       
                        </div>
                        <div class="forgot register-footer" style="display:none">
                             <span>Already have an account?</span>
                             <a href="javascript: showLoginForm();">Login</a>
                        </div>
      <div class="forgot password-footer"  >
                            <span>Forget
                                 <a href="javascript: showPasswordForm();">Password</a>
                            ?</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        openLoginModal();
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you try `<a href="#" onclick="javascript: showPasswordForm();">Password</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

showPasswordForm should be called onclick.

```js
/*
 *
 * login-register modal
 * Autor: Creative Tim
 * Web-autor: creative.tim
 * Web script: http://creative-tim.com
 *
 */
function showRegisterForm(){
    $('.loginBox').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('.registerBox').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.login-footer').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $('.register-footer').fadeIn('fast');

        });
        $('.modal-title').html('Register with');
    });
    $('.error').removeClass('alert alert-danger').html('');

}

function showPasswordForm(){
   $('#loginModal .loginBox').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('.passwordBox').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.login-footer').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $('.register-footer').fadeIn('fast');

        });
        $('.modal-title').html('Forget Password');
    });
    $('.error').removeClass('alert alert-danger').html('');
}
function showLoginForm(){
    $('#loginModal .registerBox').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('.loginBox').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.register-footer').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $('.login-footer').fadeIn('fast');
        });
        
       

        $('.modal-title').html('Login with');
    });
     $('.error').removeClass('alert alert-danger').html('');
}



function openLoginModal(){
    showLoginForm();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');
    }, 230);

}
function openRegisterModal(){
    showRegisterForm();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');
    }, 230);

}
function openPasswordModal(){
    showPasswordForm();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');
    }, 230);

}
function loginAjax(){
    /*   Remove this comments when moving to server
    $.post( "/login", function( data ) {
            if(data == 1){
                window.location.replace("/home");
            } else {
                 shakeModal();
            }
        });
    */

/*   Simulate error message from the server   */
     shakeModal();
}

function shakeModal(){
    $('#loginModal .modal-dialog').addClass('shake');
             $('.error').addClass('alert alert-danger').html("Invalid email/password combination");
             $('input[type="password"]').val('');
             setTimeout( function(){
                $('#loginModal .modal-dialog').removeClass('shake');
    }, 1000 );
}
```

```css
/*
 *
 * login-register modal
 * Autor: Creative Tim
 * Web-autor: creative.tim
 * Web script: http://creative-tim.com
 * 
 */
 
/*  Shake animation  */

@charset "UTF-8";

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
      -o-animation-duration: 1s;
         animation-duration: 1s;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
      -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
         animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.animated.hinges {
 -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
      -o-animation-duration: 2s;
         animation-duration: 2s;
}

.animated.slow {
 -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
      -o-animation-duration: 3s;
         animation-duration: 3s;
}

.animated.snail {
 -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 4s;
      -o-animation-duration: 4s;
         animation-duration: 4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake {
 0%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0);}
 10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);}
 20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-webkit-transform: translateX(10px);}
}

@-moz-keyframes shake {
 0%, 100% {-moz-transform: translateX(0);}
 10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-moz-transform: translateX(-10px);}
 20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-moz-transform: translateX(10px);}
}

@-o-keyframes shake {
 0%, 100% {-o-transform: translateX(0);}
 10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-o-transform: translateX(-10px);}
 20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-o-transform: translateX(10px);}
}

@keyframes shake {
 0%, 100% {transform: translateX(0);}
 10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {transform: translateX(-10px);}
 20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {transform: translateX(10px);}
}

.shake {
 -webkit-animation-name: shake;
 -moz-animation-name: shake;
 -o-animation-name: shake;
 animation-name: shake;
}

.login .modal-dialog{
    width: 350px;
}
.login .modal-footer{
    border-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px;
}
.login .modal-header {
    border: 0 none;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px;
/*     padding: 11px 15px; */
}
.login .modal-body{
/*     background-color: #eeeeee; */
}
.login .division {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto 18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.login .division .line {
    border-top: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 34%;
}
.login .division .line.l {
    left: 0;
}
.login .division .line.r {
    right: 0;
}
.login .division span {
    color: #424242;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.login .box .social {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.login .social .circle{
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 17px;
    padding: 15px;
}
.login .social .circle .fa{
    font-size: 16px;
}
.login .social .facebook{
    background-color: #455CA8;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.login .social .google{
    background-color: #F74933;
}
.login .social .github{
    background-color: #403A3A;
}
.login .facebook:hover{
    background-color: #6E83CD;
}
.login .google:hover{
    background-color: #FF7566;
}
.login .github:hover{
    background-color: #4D4D4d;;
}
.login .forgot {
    color: #797979;
    margin-left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.login .btn-login, .registerBox .passwordBox .btn-register{
    background-color: #00BBFF;
    border-color: #00BBFF;
    border-width: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}
.login .btn-login:hover, .registerBox .passwordBox .btn-register:hover{
    background-color: #00A4E4;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.login .form-control{
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) inset;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.login .form-control:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.16);
}
.login .form-control:focus{
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) inset;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.login .box .form input[type="text"], .login .box .form input[type="password"] {
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 46px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 13px 12px;
    width: 100%;
}


@media (max-width:400px){
    .login .modal-dialog{
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.big-login, .big-register{
    background-color: #00bbff;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border-width: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 16px 60px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.big-login:hover{
    background-color: #00A4E4;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.big-register{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0);
    color: #00bbff;
    border-color: #00bbff;
}
.big-register:hover{
    border-color: #00A4E4;
    color:  #00A4E4;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login/Register Modal by Creative Tim</title>

 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />


 <style>body{padding-top: 60px;}</style>

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                 <a class="btn big-login" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLoginModal();">Log in</a>
                 <a class="btn big-register" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openRegisterModal();">Register</a></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        </div>


   <div class="modal fade login" id="loginModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog login animated">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Login with</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="box">
                             <div class="content">
                                <div class="social">
                                    <a class="circle github" href="#">
                                        <i class="fa fa-github fa-fw"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a id="google_login" class="circle google" href="#">
                                        <i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a id="facebook_login" class="circle facebook" href="#">
                                        <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="division">
                                    <div class="line l"></div>
                                      <span>or</span>
                                    <div class="line r"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="error"></div>
                                <div class="form loginBox">
                                    <form method="" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                                    <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                                    <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                                    <input class="btn btn-default btn-login" type="button" value="Login" onclick="loginAjax()">
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="content registerBox" style="display:none;">
                             <div class="form">
                                <form method="" html="{:multipart=>true}" data-remote="true" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                                <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                                <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                                <input id="password_confirmation" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="password_confirmation">
                                <input class="btn btn-default btn-register" type="button" value="Create account" name="commit">
                                </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      <div class="box">
                            <div class="contents passwordBox" style="display:none;">
                             <div class="form">
                                <form method=""  accept-charset="UTF-8">
                                <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="Phonne">
                                <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                                <input class="btn btn-default btn-register" type="button" value="Update" name="commit">
                                </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="forgot login-footer">
                            <span>Looking to
                                 <a href="javascript: showRegisterForm();">create an account</a>
                            ?</span>
       
                        </div>
                        <div class="forgot register-footer" style="display:none">
                             <span>Already have an account?</span>
                             <a href="javascript: showLoginForm();">Login</a>
                        </div>
      <div class="forgot password-footer"  >
                            <span>Forget
                                 <a href="#" onclick="showPasswordForm();">Password</a>
                            ?</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        openLoginModal();
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When i click Login then form does not go login screen

Comment: You have same issue on all click events. Replace all href="javascript: some();" with href="#" and onclick="some()"